# Silverlight MVVM wire usercontrols to viewmodels

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, user-controls, binding

I am at a loss over something that is probably incredibly simple.
I did search but faield to find an exact answer that i needed.

The problem is as followed.

I am teaching myself silverlight MVVM.
Currently I'm writing an application that uses 1 mainpage and 2 usercontrolls.

As you can imagine, 3 viewmodels.

Currently in my XAML:

mainpage.xaml

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:newFileupload.ViewModel"
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:newFileupload.View"

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <vw:PicturesOverviewView />
</Grid>
```

PicturesOverviewView.xaml

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

</Grid>
```

So in mainpage.xaml, I set the datacontext in xaml, i then call the usercontrol in the grid like so:

```
<vw:PicturesOverviewView />
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot create an instance of "PicturesOverviewView".    C:\Programming\C#\newFileUpload\newFileupload\MainPage.xaml 16  9   newFileupload
```

I have absolutely no clue what is causing this, and secondly..

How do I bind view models to the appropriate usercontrol?

Do I need to declare the view namespace for every usercontrol and then set its datacontext like the mainpage?

Thanks for taking the time to read and I hope to be able to continue soon :)

Comment: Bind your view to a vm like you are, then bind controls etc to data that lives in the viewmodel.  So if uc1 is a ListBox bind it to the customers list that lives on MainPageViewModel.

Comment: @Derek Beattie : I want a different viewmodel for my usercontrol(unless really not possible) and it still doesnt clear the error i got. I can't even load the usercontrol :(

Comment: I duplicated your example (guessing the content of each component based on the details given) and it compiles and runs fine. Can you provide more of your code/Xaml? The "Cannot Create" may be a problem with PicturesOverviewView rather than the main page, but you don't say where it is created either.

Comment: Post all of the xaml for main and the user control.

Comment: @Derek Beattie & HiTech Mahic, just posted the xaml. Want to know what causes the error, and how to bind a viewmodel to PicturesOverviewView. It generates another error if i try to bind it like in mainpage.xaml.

Comment: That code can't be right. You are creating a PicturesOverviewView inside the PicturesOverviewView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code shown is correct, you are attempting to create a PicturesOverviewView control inside a PicturesOverviewView control. That will account for the compile error. (I am guessing though that you have cut & Paste the same Xaml twice).

Binding-wise:
You want to bind the child controls to properties on the main view Model, that are themselves view models

e.g.

```
namespace newFileupload.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public ChildViewModel1 ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }
        public ChildViewModel2 ChildViewModel2 { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            this.ChildViewModel1 = new ChildViewModel1() { SomeProperty = "hello"};
            this.ChildViewModel2 = new ChildViewModel2() { SomeProperty = "there" };
        }
    }
}
```

Then the MainPage binds like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <vw:PicturesOverviewView DataContext="{Binding Path=ChildViewModel1}" />
    <vw:PicturesOverviewView DataContext="{Binding Path=ChildViewModel2}" />
</Grid>
```

Something somewhere needs to create your view models with the right data. It makes sense to hangs the children off the parent viewmodel.

I would suggest you look at using IOC injection (e.g. using Unity) as it sounds like you may simply wish to create singletons referenced at various levels. The issue is where do you want to provide re-use as if you hard-wire data contexts in the child views you cannot reuse them.

Comment: You are right, I made an error there. Im not trying to create a view in the same view. sorry about that. also, I want an individual viewmodel for mainpage and picturesoverviewview. It works fine in WPF. just not in silverlight. im using 4.0

Comment: They can have their own, but if you create each as a static member of the view model per view you are not doing anything much different from using code behind. It is really about where to hang them. For simple MVVM nest the child view models in the parent viewmodel as properties and bind the child controls to the child viewmodels. I am trying to update my answer to cover this as we speak. You might want to check the Xaml you posted as it is the same lot twice.

Comment: Ah I see where your going with the viewmodel binding. Thanks for that ^^ now to solve the error so I can actually see what im doing in the designer. I updated my post again. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Aaah... so thats how you set the datacontext. thanks alot! :) this helps immensely. This actually cleared the error aswell btw. Marked your answer as the answer. Thanks again. Can finally continue :)

Comment: I am doing the binding bit of my example from memory, but if anything shown does not work just let me know and I will update it.

Comment: Your memory didn't let you down. Everything works as it should now. And thanks for the info about IoC. Heard about it before, don't think its nescesary. It's supposed to be a bit simple. A fileuploader, written by me to learn silverlight, implemented in my asp.net MVC CMS :)